# Can't connect to secondary members in a replica Set

Tags: mongodb, slave, replicaset

I've created a mongodb replica set with 3 members.
They are synchronized, but if I try to connect to secondary members via Robomongo and via webapp it does not work. I get the error for the slaveOK is set to false, but I've just set rs.slaveOk() to each member of the replica set.

If I connect via shell I do not get the error and I can list everything.
If a secondary member becomes primary I can read from it also via Robomongo.

MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10

here is the rs.status()

```
rs:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "gmrrs",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-06-25T16:14:53Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "****",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 2014,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1435246594, 1208),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-06-25T15:36:34Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1435248124, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2015-06-25T16:02:04Z"),
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "***:27019",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 774,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1435246594, 1208),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-06-25T15:36:34Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-06-25T16:14:52Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-06-25T16:14:52Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "syncingTo" : "****:27018"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "****:27020",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 759,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1435246594, 1208),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-06-25T15:36:34Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-06-25T16:14:51Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-06-25T16:14:51Z"),
            "pingMs" : 1,
            "syncingTo" : "***:27018"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

and here the rs.conf()

```
 rs:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "rs",
    "version" : 3,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "***:27018"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "***:27019"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "***:27020"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to write on just one server and read to all of them.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Nicola

Answer (score 0):

Robomongo currently can't query secondary instances in a replica set: https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/116

Comment: It is better to include the relevant parts of the link in the body of your answer, so that the content is still present should the link go down or be changed in the future.